# How to display moving text field during other jQuery animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to replicate the loading page at http://www.alessioatzeni.com/ but the percentage loaded text on my page will not display until the loading line animation completes. You can see my project page at https://jaredblumer.github.io/atzeniStudy/

If you inspect the HTML using Chrome Developer Tools, you'll see that the #loader-percentage span text is dynamically updating, but for a reason unbeknownst to me the text is not displaying until after the line animation ends.

The code I am currently using for this is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div id="loader" class="loader">
  <span id="loader-line" class="loader-line">
    <span id="loader-percentage" class="loader-percentage"></span>
  </span>

</div>
```

**Javascript (loader.js)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Loading Page
  var pageLoader = function() {

    var $elements = $('body').find('img[src]');

    $('body [style]').each(function(){
      var src = $(this).css('background-image').replace(/^url\(["']?/, '').replace(/["']?\)$/, '');

      if(src) {
        $elements = $elements.add($('<img src="' + src + '"/>'));
      }
    });

    var $loading = $('#loader');
    var $loadPercentageLine = $('#loader-line');
    var $loadPercentageText = $('#loader-percentage');
    var elementsLoaded = 0;
    var speed = 5000;

    var animatePercentage = function(e) {

      console.log(e);
      $loadPercentageText.text(parseInt(e));

    };

    var loading = function() {

      var percentage = 0;

      if ($elements.length) {
        percentage = parseInt((elementsLoaded / $elements.length) * 100);
      }

      $loadPercentageLine.stop().animate({
        height:percentage + '%'
      }, speed);

      $loadPercentageText.stop().animate({
        percentage:percentage
      }, {
        duration: speed,
        step: animatePercentage
      });
    };

    if($elements.length) {
      loading();

      $elements.each(function() {
        elementsLoaded++;
        loading();
      });
    }
  };

  pageLoader();

});
```

Comment: the loader text is not visible because the loader line is not high enough. place the text outside the line container and you will see the text. you could also use `::after` instead of an div element for the text and place it via css right next to the line.

Answer (score 0):

here is solution:

```
.loader-line{
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```